# WoW Profession bonuses

Tags: world-of-warcraft

I would like to know what the bonuses are for the professions in WoW. For example, the gems with extra large stats that only the Jewelcrafter himself can use, or the bonus sockets you can put on your own gear as a Blacksmith. What are the bonuses for the other professions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Taken right off of [MMO Champion](http://www.mmo-champion.com/threads/1285053-Professions-in-MoP-and-their-respective-bonuses?p=20815039#post20815039)

**Profession Perks:**

***Mining:*** Toughness (+480 Stamina)

***Herbalism:*** Lifeblood (+480 Haste)

***Skinning:*** Master of Anatomy (+480 Critical Strike)

***Tailoring:***

Swordguard Embroidery (-180 Critical Strike, Hit or -200 Stamina; +1,000 Attack Power)

Lightweave Embroidery (+320 Intellect)

Darkglow Embroidery (-180 Intellect +750 Spirit)

***Leatherworking:***

Fur Lining - Strength (+320 Strength)

Fur Lining - Agility (+320 Agility)

Fur Lining - Intellect (+320 Intellect)

Fur Lining - Stamina (-170 Mastery, Dodge; +750 Stamina)

***Blacksmithing:*** Socket Bracer & Socket Gloves

+320 Strength, Agility, Intellect or

+480 Stamina or

+640 PvP Power, PvP Resilience, Mastery, Critical Strike, Haste, Hit, Expertise, Spirit, Dodge, Parry

***Jewelcrafting:*** Jeweler's Facet*2

+320 Strength, Agility, Intellect, Mastery, Critical Strike, Haste, Hit, Expertise, Spirit, Dodge, Parry or

+480 Stamina or

+640 1/2/3 PvP Power, 1/2/3 PvP Resilience

***Engineering:***

Synapse Springs (+320 Strength, Agility, Intellect)

Phase Fingers (+480 Dodge)

Incendiary Fireworks Launcher (Incendiary Fireworks every 45 sec)

*Cloak* : Permanently attaches a specialized folding assembly to a cloak, allowing you to deploy a goblin glider and fall slowly for 30 sec.  The glider has some initial thrust and allows you to turn while falling.

The cloak can only be used once every five minutes and requires an Engineering skill of at least 500 to operate.

*Belt* : Permanently attaches overpowered nitro boosts to your belt, allowing you to greatly increase run speed for 5 sec.  They rarely explode violently, so don't worry about that.

The nitro boosts can only be activated every 3 minutes and require an Engineering skill of at least 400.

***Enchanting:***

Enchant Ring - Greater Strength (+320 Strength)

Enchant Ring - Greater Agility (+320 Agility)

Enchant Ring - Greater Intellect (+320 Intellect)

Enchant Ring - Greater Stamina (+480 Stamina)

***Inscription:***

Secret Tiger Fang Inscription (+320 Strength)

Secret Tiger Claw Inscription (+320 Agility)

Secret Crane Wing Inscription (+320 Intellect)

Secret Ox Horn Inscription (+480 Stamina)

***Alchemy:***

Alchemist's Flask (+320 Strength, Agility or Intellect)

Mixology:
+320 Flask of Winter's Bite Strength, Flask of Spring Blossoms Agility, Flask of the Warm Sun Intellect or
+480 Flask of the Earth Stamina, Flask of Falling Leaves Spirit

Comment: Might want to add that engineering has the [Goblin Glider](http://www.wowhead.com/spell=126392/goblin-glider) on your cloak and [Nitro Boosts](http://www.wowhead.com/spell=55016/nitro-boosts) on your belt. Honorable mention: [resurrection](http://www.wowhead.com/item=40772).

Comment: It should be noticed that these values scale in one form or another and that this list is incomplete; it is only valid for level 90, artisian-level characters. For example, gathering professions scale with your gathering profession level, whereas item-based bonuses scale based on which item you craft (as a result of your profession and character level).

Comment: ^ Absolutely ^ you will not have +480 stamina on a lvl 20 pally with lvl 14 mining, but this answer was already very long, so i game him the endgame +/-, which is when the professions become relevant for stats and not just crafting purposes.